# How to save an "Images.xcassets" file

Tags: xcode, save

I am having some trouble saving the Images.xcassets folder in the project tree of Xcode. I use the default one with the app icons and launch images.

I was wondering if I need to explicitly save it.  If I could, how?

*Please do not vote down on this post.  If my question is unclear in any way, please explain why in the comments section or edit my post.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my experience, you shouldn't have to actually save the .xcassets file for it to operate. If you notice, simply building the project after editing the file will still apply the changes. If you quit Xcode and open it back up, your changes to the .xcassets file should still be there.

Comment: I was just wondering if any problems will result with not saving the file.

Comment: I haven't had any. If you have some, please let me know.